# How to copy and paste with offset in the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and paste all the visible rows except the first row which is the headers.

This pastes in another sheet.

```vb
With ws1.Range("A1:Q" & LastRow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Movies"
    Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End with
```

However, I must copy the data in the same sheet, and my code errors out.

```vb
With ws1.Range("A1:Q" & LastRow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Movies"
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
end with
```

I tried the same code where I assign the complete range.

```vb
With ws1.Range("A1:Q" & LastRow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Movies"
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & LastRow + 1 & ":Q" & LastRow + LastRow2)
end with
```

[image]

Comment: `.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)` missing `.`

Comment: "and my code fails" - if you get errors it's useful to describe exactly what the error is, and on which line you see it.

Comment: HI Tim, My bad, that was a copy-and-paste issue. I fixed it. The error I get when executing that line is "This Selection isnt valid. MAke sure the copy and paste are dont overlap unless they are the same size and shape" Thank you

Comment: In the second block, what's the value of `LastRow` when it fails?  FYI you have `Offset(1)` so that means you're copying from the row below `LastRow`, and you're also trying to paste to that same row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI you use (effectively)

```
ws1.Range("A1:Q" & LastRow).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

so that means *you're including the row below `LastRow` when copying*, and you're also trying to paste to that same row...

You can avoid that using `Resize()` to exclude that last row from the `Copy`

```
With ws1.Range("A1:Q" & LastRow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Movies"
    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                   Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. it works like a charm. I had no idea you could use resize. Im happy to learn new things :)